# Creating a Progress bar inside a HTML table cell

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to create a progress bar in a HTML table cell which gets it's data from Mysql, so that I can display how much my garbage bin is filled.  So far,with the help of stackoverflow  I've been able to construct this :

```
echo "<tr><td>".$row["Time"]."</td><td>".$row["nodeID"]."</td> 
<td>".$row["Location"]."</td><td><div class='bg' style='width: 20%'> 
</div>".$row["Percent_Filled"]."</td></tr>";
```

This works, but I need the progress bar width to take value from $row["Percent_Filled"]. I'm not able to do this without some or the other syntax error.

Comment: What is wrong with `echo "<tr><td>".$row["Time"]."</td><td>".$row["nodeID"]."</td> 
<td>".$row["Location"]."</td><td><div class='bg' style='width: " . $row["Percent_Filled"] . "%'> 
</div>".$row["Percent_Filled"]."</td></tr>";` ?

Comment: Thanks for you input! @James

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there, just replace `style='width: 20%'` with `style='width:". $row['Percent_Filled']."%'`